# Storing google protocol buffers on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers

I have a proto I am using to store the state of my application.
It is part of a class which I need to store.
I have tried objectify but that doesn't seem to work because protocol buffers are not a core type and have final classes. I also tried serializing the proto but that doesn't seem to work either. Can somebody help me out?

My class looks something like this

```
   public class MyClass {
     int a;
     String b;
     List<State> state;
   }
```

State is a proto which I am using to store the state. In essence I need to figure out how to store an instance of MyClass. 
Thanks,
Kartik

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to store Protobuf object in serialized format, right? At this case just store it as a `byte[]` field. You can even make this serialization/deserialization in `@PostLoad` and `@PrePersist` methods + `@Transient` for original `State` field

Answer (score -1):

App Engine stores protocol buffers internally.  Read this.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown

You can use objectify, and App Engine will store protocol buffers.  Done.

Comment: Thanks I used objectify. I wanted to use protobufs to handle client server communication.